# Issue while integrating the project with new android studio installation

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-update-sdk

I have installed latest android studio on another machine and trying to run my project which i was building on another machine. I am having the gradle build fail and don't know exactly what thing is causing the problem. [image]

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mudasir.login"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude'META-INF/license.txt'

    }
    dexOptions{
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: Did you try what it is suggesting ? Also try to do imvalidate cacje and restart and post build.gradle as well

Comment: Yeah i am trying to re download the dependencies but its not doing any thing. It tries to connect with internet and then disappears.

Comment: How to do invalidate cache..??

Comment: File -> Invalidate Cache and restart...

Comment: No bro. This did not solve the problem..

Comment: add your build.gradle file as well

Comment: in your question, edit your question and add....

Comment: Edited the question with gradle file. I dont know why gradle is showing the less information. I simply copied whole project and tried to run.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of the Gradle file. Don't use an image

Comment: Updated with the gradle file text.